# Flask Python WTForms ignoring custom styling in style sheet

Tags: python, linux, flask, wtforms

Running Flask Python on an OpenSuSE machine and I have this html template, which displays a single-dropdown list and a password field along with a 'Connect' button.
I would like to customize the 'Connect' button with my own style, like increasing the font-size or to make the button larger, etc.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  {% from "macros/fields.html" import render_text_field %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/style-wifi.css') }}">
    <title>Ad Noctem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container1">
       <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='MyLogo.png') }}">
    </div>
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
           <h3>Select Wi-Fi SSID To Connect To</h3>

        <div class="flex-parent jc-center" style="position:relative; left:20px; top:20px;">

           {% block content %}
              <form name="select_wifi" method="POST" class="form">
                 <div class="form_container">
                    {{forms.hidden_tag()}}
                    {{ render_text_field(forms.mywifi) }}
                    {{ render_text_field(forms.password) }}

                    {{ forms.wificonnect(class_="button button--form") }}

                 </div>
              </form>
           {% endblock %}


        </div>
        <div id="mybutton">
             <button class="homebutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'index';">HOME</button>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this style sheet but the form button is rendered using default style and no matter what I have in the style sheet has any effect on the button style. What am I doing wrong?

```
    html {
     background-color: #D9D9DD;
     font-size: 12px;
/*     font-family: "Courier New", courier-new; */
     font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

img {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

h1 {
   color: #0F0F70;
   font-size: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   }

h2 {
   color: #0F0F70;
   font-size: 30px;
   line-height: 2;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-align: center;
  }

h3 {
   color: #0F0F70;
   font-size: 30px;
   line-height: 2;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-align: center;
  }

div.container1 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   align-items: flex-start;
}

div.container2 {
   text-align: center;
}

ol.myol {
   color: black;
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
}

li {
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 2;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   }

div.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

div.jc-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

button.margin-right {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.pushable {
    background: hsl(0deg 0% 36%);
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline-offset: 4px;
  }

.front {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: hsl(0deg 0% 46%);
    color: black;
    transform: translateY(-6px);
  }

.pushable:active .front {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
  }

.homebutton {
  background-color: #D9D9DD;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: black;
}

#mybutton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 10px;
}

ol.buttonol {
     counter-reset: olCounter;
}

li.buttonli {
     counter-increment: olCounter;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
}

li.buttonli button::before {
     content: counter(olCounter" ". ";
}


.form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 -0.2rem;
  background-color: #D9D9DD;
}

.form_container {
  padding: 2.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.form_group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form_label {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form_field {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem;
  background-color: #D9D9DD;
}


.form_field:focus {
  border-bottom: blue;
}

.button--form {
/*  margin: 2rem 0 0 auto; */
  padding: 0.75rem 3rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #D9D9DD;
}

.button--form:hover {
  background-color: #D9D9DD;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-SJ

Comment: Hi, Can someone help me with this issue?